# Custom alert dialogbox error

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, fragment

Hi guys thanks in advance ...

I am trying to show an alert dialog in my activity but I am getting some error ....

I followed code from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog last section of that link ....

[image]

same mine see below

[image]

and as shown there I wrote code

[image]

and my code is below which is called on button click

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
Context mContext;
mContext = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.search_root));
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setView(layout);
alertDialog = builder.create(); 
alertDialog.show();
```

and only difference is

```
public class CatalogueActivity extends FragmentActivity{
```

and it shows error like below

[image]

I hope you understand my problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using **getApplicationContext()**, you should use `this` keyword which refers to activity's context.

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: what is the difference between this and getApplicationContext(); isn't it same ?

Comment: no, the are not exactly same. Application's context is tied to application life-cycle and Activity's context is tied to an activity life-cycle. You cant use application's context to show Toast, Dialog or Progress windows etc.